# graph_tool: how to avoid that all_circuits function block my script

Tags: python, graph-tool

I'm learning python and I'm doing some experiment with the module graph_tool.
Since the function all_circuits could take a long time to calculate all the cycles, is there a way to stop the function (for example after "X" seconds or after the iterator reaches a certain size) and continue the execution of the script?
Thanks

Comment: if you will run code in separated Process then you can terminale/kill it - but it can make other problems because it needs to send all data to other process and someone get results. Processes don't share data and objects. Using `threading` you could share data but it doesn't have method to terminate/kill it and it need special methods. Similar problem with killing process/thread was few times in last few days. [python - Is there any way to kill a Thread? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple, actually. The function `all_circuits()` returns an iterator over all circuits. Therefore, if you want to stop early, all you need is to break the iterations:

```
g = collection.ns["football"]
for i, c in enumerate(all_circuits(g)):
    if i > 10:
        print(c)
        break
```

which prints

```
[  0   1  25  24  11  10   5   4   9   8   7   6   2   3  26  12  13  15
  14  38  18  19  29  30  35  34  31  32  21  20  17  16  23  22  47  46
  49  48  44  45  33  37  36  43  42  57  56  27  62  61  54  39  60  59
  58  63  64 100  99  89  88  83  53  52  40  41  67  68  50  28  69  70
  65  66  75  76  95  87  86  80  79  55  94  82  81  72  74  73 110 114
 104  93]
```

and stops.